# Create std::string from std::span of unsigned char

Tags: c++, c++20, stdstring, std-span

I am using a C library which uses various fixed-sized `unsigned char` arrays with no null terminator as strings.

I've been converting them to `std::string` using the following function:

```cpp
auto uchar_to_stdstring(const unsigned char* input_array, int width) -> std::string {
  std::string temp_string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(input_array), width);
  temp_string.erase(temp_string.find_last_not_of(' ') + 1);

  return temp_string;
}
```

Which works fine, other than the use of `reinterpret_cast`, the need to pass the array size and the fact that I'm decaying an array into a pointer. I'm trying to avoid all of these issues with the use of `std::span`.

The function that uses `std::span` looks like this:

```cpp
auto ucharspan_to_stdstring(const std::span<unsigned char>& input_array) -> std::string {
  std::stringstream temp_ss;

  for (const auto& input_arr_char : input_array) {
    temp_ss << input_arr_char;
  }

  return temp_ss.str();
}
```

The function works well, makes everything else simpler without having to track the C array's size. But, a little further digging with some benchmarking (using [nanobench](https://github.com/martinus/nanobench)) shows that the new function is many times slower than the classic `reinterpret_cast` method. My assumption is that the `for` loop in the `std::span`-based function is the inefficiency here.

**My question:** Is there a more efficient method to convert a fixed-size C array of unsigned chars from a `std::span` variable to a `std::string`?

---

Edit:

`gcc` benchmark (-O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++20, nanobench, minEpochIterations=54552558, warmup=100, doNotOptimizeAway)

| relative | ns/op | op/s | err% | ins/op | bra/op | miss% | total | uchar[] to std::string |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100.0% | 5.39 | 185,410,438.12 | 0.3% | 80.00 | 20.00 | 0.0% | 3.56 | `uchar` |
| 2.1% | 253.06 | 3,951,678.30 | 0.6% | 4,445.00 | 768.00 | 0.0% | 167.74 | `ucharspan` |
| 1,244.0% | 0.43 | 2,306,562,499.69 | 0.2% | 9.00 | 1.00 | 0.0% | 0.29 | `ucharspan_barry` |
| 72.8% | 7.41 | 134,914,127.56 | 1.3% | 99.00 | 22.00 | 0.0% | 4.89 | `uchar_bsv` |

`clang` benchmark (-O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++20, nanobench, minEpochIterations=54552558, warmup=100, doNotOptimizeAway)

| relative | ns/op | op/s | err% | ins/op | bra/op | miss% | total | uchar[] to std::string |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100.0% | 2.13 | 468,495,014.11 | 0.2% | 14.00 | 1.00 | 0.0% | 1.42 | `uchar` |
| 0.8% | 251.74 | 3,972,418.54 | 0.2% | 4,477.00 | 767.00 | 0.0% | 166.30 | `ucharspan` |
| 144.4% | 1.48 | 676,329,668.07 | 0.1% | 7.00 | 0.00 | 95.8% | 0.98 | `ucharspan_barry` |
| 34.5% | 6.19 | 161,592,563.70 | 0.1% | 80.00 | 24.00 | 0.0% | 4.08 | `uchar_bsv` |

(`uchar_bsv` in the benchmarks is the same as `ucharspan_barry`, but with a `std::basic_string_view<unsigned char const>` parameter instead of `std::span<unsigned char const>`

Comment: Why the `erase`?

Comment: Why not std::string_view?

Comment: @Barry, the erase was needed as some strings had suffixing spaces that needed removing

Comment: @Simog `string_view is a signed char` No it isn't. It's `char`. But that's beside my point. I actually meant  `basic_string_view` which is a template. You can just use `std::basic_string_view<unsigned char>`

Comment: Probably with the iterations and filled branch predictor (etc.) conversion gets unrealistically fast now. But Barry seems to be the winner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want:

```cpp
auto ucharspan_to_stdstring(std::span<unsigned char const> input_array) -> std::string {
    return std::string(input_array.begin(), input_array.end());
}
```

`string`, like other stand library containers, is constructible from an appropriate iterator pair - and this is such a pair. Since these are random access iterators, this will do a single allocation, etc.

Note that I changed from `span<T> const&` to `span<T const>`, for two reasons. First, you're not mutating the contents of the span, so the inner type needs to be `const`... similar to how you took a `T const*`, not a `T*`. Second, you should take `span`s by value because they're cheap to copy (unless you very specifically need the identity of the span, which you don't here).

It may be better to do a `reinterpret_cast` so that you can use the `(char const*, size_t)` constructor - this one ensures a single `memcpy` for the eventual write. But you'd have to time it to see if it's worthwhile.